# Экспорт данных из text_box в excel (C# WF)

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

Пишу программу на C# WF, и мне нужно, чтобы записанные в текстбокс данные, сохранялись в экселе по порядку, в одну строку. Программа чем-то напоминает анкету с фио, телефоном, и так далее. Никак не могу настроить экспорт, помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: ну вы покажите что пытались хоть, а то ваш вопрос выглядит не как вопрос, а как техзадание

Comment: Нечего показывать, так как сначала пробовал с вордом и oledb, но ничего толком не вышло. Ищу именно экземплы по реализации.

Comment: ну так вам в ворд или эксель надо? В какой формат? CSV? XLS? XSLX? [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Getting-Started) пробовали?

Comment: Мне нужен конкретно эксель

Comment: какой из форматов?

Comment: А пробовали сначала поискать и попробовать, что сам Микрософт [предлагает](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects)?

Answer (score 3):

Никогда раньше с Excel файлами не работал, решил помочь вам, а заодно и самому познакомится с рекомендованной уважаемым tym32167 библиотекой [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Getting-Started).

Получилась такая маленькая программка.
[image: пример работы проги]

Создаем такой класс модели

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public string ForList => $"{LastName} {FirstName}";
}
```

Создадим и добавим в проект с таким содержимым файл
[image: пример открытого в экселе файла]

Вот такой класс Репозитория получился у меня. Вполне возможно, что с этой библиотекой можно работать более эффективным образом, потому критика приветствуется.

```
public class EpplusRepository : IRepository
{
    private const string _FILE_NAME = @"Data\Phonebook.xlsx";
    private readonly string _pathToFile;
    private FileInfo _workingFile;

    //ctor
    public EpplusRepository()
    {
        _pathToFile = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, _FILE_NAME);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Получение ссылки на файл
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private FileInfo GetFileInfo()
    {
        if (_workingFile == null)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(_pathToFile)) throw new Exception($"Файл не найден: {_pathToFile}");
            _workingFile = new FileInfo(_pathToFile);
        }

        return _workingFile;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Получение полного списка людей
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        List<Person> result = new List<Person>();

        using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(GetFileInfo()))
        using (ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets[1])
        {
            //регион заполненных ячеек
            var dim = ws.Dimension;
            //читаем строки, наполняем коллекцию людей
            var columns = new List<string>();
            //пропускаем первую строку, т.к. она содержит заголовки
            for (int row = dim.Start.Row + 1; row <= dim.End.Row; row++)
            {
                //читаем строку
                columns.Clear();
                for (int column = dim.Start.Column; column <= dim.End.Column; column++)
                {
                    var value = ws.Cells[row, column].Value?.ToString();

                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) value = "<?>";
                    columns.Add(value);
                }

                //добавляем нового в коллекцию
                var person = new Person
                {
                    Id = row,
                    FirstName = columns[0],
                    LastName = columns[1],
                    Address = columns[2],
                    Phone = columns[3]
                };
                result.Add(person);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Получение записи по Id  равному номеру строки в файле
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Person GetPerson(int id)
    {
        Person person = null;

        using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(GetFileInfo()))
        using (ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets[1])
        {
            //регион заполненных ячеек
            var dim = ws.Dimension;
            //пропускаем первую строку, т.к. она содержит заголовки
            if (id > dim.Start.Row && id <= dim.End.Row)
            {
                //читаем строку
                var columns = new List<string>();
                for (int column = dim.Start.Column; column <= dim.End.Column; column++)
                {
                    var value = ws.Cells[id, column].Value.ToString();
                    columns.Add(value);
                }

                //присваиваем значения свойствам
                person = new Person();
                person.Id = id;
                person.FirstName = columns[0];
                person.LastName = columns[1];
                person.Address = columns[2];
                person.Phone = columns[3];
            }

        }

        return person;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Вставка новой записи
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="person"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public int AddPerson(Person person)
    {
        if (person == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(person));

        int result = 0;

        using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(GetFileInfo()))
        using (ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets[1])
        {
            //регион заполненных ячеек
            var dim = ws.Dimension;
            //вычисляем номера строк и столбцов
            result = dim.End.Row + 1;
            int cFirstName = dim.Start.Column;
            int cLastName = dim.Start.Column + 1;
            int cAddress = dim.Start.Column + 2;
            int cPhone = dim.Start.Column + 3;

            //присваиваем значения
            ws.Cells[result, cFirstName].Value = person.FirstName;
            ws.Cells[result, cLastName].Value = person.LastName;
            ws.Cells[result, cAddress].Value = person.Address;
            ws.Cells[result, cPhone].Value = person.Phone;

            //сохраняем
            pck.Save();
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Обновление нужной записи
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="person"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool UpdatePerson(Person person)
    {
        if (person == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(person));

        bool result = false;

        using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(GetFileInfo()))
        using (ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets[1])
        {
            //регион заполненных ячеек
            var dim = ws.Dimension;

            if (person.Id > dim.Start.Row && person.Id <= dim.End.Row)
            {
                //вычисляем номера столбцов
                int cFirstName = dim.Start.Column;
                int cLastName = dim.Start.Column + 1;
                int cAddress = dim.Start.Column + 2;
                int cPhone = dim.Start.Column + 3;

                //присваиваем значения
                ws.Cells[person.Id, cFirstName].Value = person.FirstName;
                ws.Cells[person.Id, cLastName].Value = person.LastName;
                ws.Cells[person.Id, cAddress].Value = person.Address;
                ws.Cells[person.Id, cPhone].Value = person.Phone;

                //сохраняем
                pck.Save();
                result = true;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Удаление строки из файла по ее номеру
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool RemovePerson(int id)
    {
        bool result = false;

        using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(GetFileInfo()))
        using (ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets[1])
        {
            //регион заполненных ячеек
            var dim = ws.Dimension;

            if (id > dim.Start.Row && id <= dim.End.Row)
            {
                //удаляем строку с нужным номером
                ws.DeleteRow(id);

                result = true;
            }

            //сохраняем
            pck.Save();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Весь пример можно скачать [здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/PNT335JTsV5VdA)